# IIS user (not a Windows user) - how to encrypt password in msdeploy script.bat?

Tags: iis

A script on the build server uses ms-deploy. One of the switches is for the username and password. The user is an IIS user (web handler). Is there a way to avoid putting the password in the .bat file?

```
msdeploy -verb:sync source:contentPath=C:\bamboodata\xml-data\build-dir\HEL-   HEL-JOB1\Precompiled,includeAcls=false 
-dest:contentPath="%_APPNAME%/%_APPNAME%",computerName=%_LOCATION-SERVER%:%_PORT%/MsDeploy.axd?site=%_SITE%,Username='Team- username',Password='Team-password',AuthType='Basic' -allowUntrusted
```

Am guessing Powershell can resolve? (I've never used Powershell)

Answer (score 0):

MSDeploy includes an option to store and then retrieve the credentials from the Windows credential store.

First run your msdeploy command with an additional parameter **storeCredentials='TeamID'**.  Manually run this on your build server.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync source:contentPath=C:\bamboodata\xml-data\build-dir\HEL-   HEL-JOB1\Precompiled,includeAcls=false -dest:contentPath="%_APPNAME%/%_APPNAME%",computerName=%_LOCATION-SERVER%:%_PORT%/MsDeploy.axd?site=%_SITE%,Username='Team- username',Password='Team-password',storeCredentials='TeamID',AuthType='Basic' -allowUntrusted
```

Replacing TeamID with a unique name of your choice.  This is the identifier for the user/pass set.

After this, you can completely omit the user/pass from your batch script by including the **getCredentials='TeamID'** parameter

```
msdeploy -verb:sync source:contentPath=C:\bamboodata\xml-data\build-dir\HEL-   HEL-JOB1\Precompiled,includeAcls=false -dest:contentPath="%_APPNAME%/%_APPNAME%",computerName=%_LOCATION-SERVER%:%_PORT%/MsDeploy.axd?site=%_SITE%,getCredentials='TeamID',AuthType='Basic' -allowUntrusted
```

For more information:

http://blogs.iis.net/jamescoo/webdeployment-tool-now-works-with-credential-store